# Reledmac: Add chapter into endnotes

Tags: endnotes, reledmac

I have a book containing letters. After all the letters i want to print the endnotes containing commentary. So the endnotes should look like this:

> Letter 1
>
> p. 4) Word: This is a comment
>
> Letter 2
>
> p. 6) Another word: Another comment

(If it's easier to achieve, it could also be that the separators have page references)

A problem is, that the chapter-title is not in the numbered area. There is a function in reledmac where you can achieve this with 
\doendnotesbysection
but this would be tedious, as i have more than 500 letters to attend to.

Is there a simple way to just change the \chapter-command to immediately write it's name into the endnotes file?

This is what I got so far:

```
 \documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letter 1}

\beginnumbering
\pstart This is the first letter, containing a critical \edtext{note}{\Aendnote{This is what it's all about}}.
\pend
\endnumbering

\chapter{Letter 2}

\beginnumbering
\pstart This is the second letter, containing another critical \edtext{comment}{\Aendnote{This should be separated from the note above with a line containing "Letter 2"}}.
\pend
\endnumbering

\newpage
\doendnotes{A}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, I have read two time you question and I don't understand well. What do you mean to "Is there a simple way to just change the \chapter-command to immediately write it's name into the endnotes file?" ?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to make myself clear. I imagine something like: \newcommand{\chapterendnotes}[1]{\chapter{#1}\addtoendnotes{A}{#1}} would do. But i'm not able to get this to work.

Comment: ok, but what do you want to add? what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Say I would want to edit this page in print with notes: http://law2.umkc.edu/faculty/projects/ftrials/wilde/lettersfromwilde.html first i would write \chapter{Letter 1} then in the numbered text: Your \edtext{sonnet}{\Aendnote{A type of poetry}} ... and then the next: \chapter{Letter 2} where in \beginnumbering would start again and the text would be: \pstart March 1893, \edtext{Savoy Hotel}{\Aendnote{A hotel in ..}} and so on. The Endnotes would now contain the Letter 1 and Letter 2 so that i can easily now to which letter the comment of Savoy Hotel belongs.

Comment: oh, I saw. not actually possible but open an issue on github. I could look on it.

Comment: Sorry, so stupid. Why do you not doing `\chapter{XX}\doendnotes{A}`?

Comment: Ah, that's the misunderstanding: The endnotes should all be printed at the end of the book. And because there are 500 letters it would be nice to look through the endnotes and know to which letter one comment belongs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34186/discussion-between-maieul-and-martin-mueller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version 2.12.0 of reledmac, just uploaded on CTAN, add a `toendnotes` command which allow you to insert any arbitrary code inside the endnote auxiliary file, arbitrary code which will executed when typesetting the endnotes.

For example, you can do

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letter 1}

\beginnumbering \toendnotes{\chapter{Letter 1}}
\pstart This is the first letter, containing a critical \edtext{note}{\Aendnote{This is what it's all about}}.
\pend
\endnumbering

\chapter{Letter 2}

\beginnumbering \toendnotes{\chapter{Letter 2}}
\pstart This is the second letter, containing another critical \edtext{comment}{\Aendnote{This should be separated from the note above with a line containing "Letter 2"}}.
\pend
\endnumbering

\newpage
\doendnotes{A}

\end{document}
```

However, in your case, as you use a `\beginnumbering` for each `chapter`, you can just use the already existing command `\doendnotesbysection`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Letter 1}

\beginnumbering 
\pstart This is the first letter, containing a critical \edtext{note}{\Aendnote{This is what it's all about}}.
\pend
\endnumbering

\chapter{Letter 2}

\beginnumbering 
\pstart This is the second letter, containing another critical \edtext{comment}{\Aendnote{This should be separated from the note above with a line containing "Letter 2"}}.
\pend
\endnumbering

\newpage
\chapter{Letter 1}
\doendnotesbysection{A}
\chapter{Letter 2}
\doendnotesbysection{A}

\end{document}
```